# Software Crashes after Power Outage

Tags: windows-10, crash

I experienced a power outage a few nights ago. I have two systems; one for my banking, etc., the other is a "crash and burn" system on which I practice with Power BI, SQL Server, ERWin, and other products; and most recently a mainframe course that I'm taking.

Both systems run Windows 10 [with most current updates] and are protected by APC surge protectors and battery back up. Both systems shut down after the period specified in PowerChute profile. My household system recovered; I'm back to normal.

On the C&B system, it's not the case. I can't seem to get most software stay running once it's loaded. That's true for the browsers and even Windows management software [I noticed that the hard drive was pegged at 100% and tried Windows utilities all of which would crashed.] I load the software; but once I try to use the app, it crashes.

I tried re-installing the browsers; that didn't work. The 3270 terminal emulator that I need for my course works w/o problem; most other apps crash like the browsers do.

Am I faced with re-installing Windows or is there an easier way out of this mess?

Thanks,
Nicholas

Comment: Were you fussing with write-cache settings on this server?

Comment: No fussing with write-cache settings.  Guess, I'll have to re-install/repair Windows once I get another response or two that suggest that.

Comment: Look in the Event Viewer for related messages. See if you have `.dmp` files inside `C:\Windows\Minidump`. Try to test Windows integrity by running the commands [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html) and then [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: Before reinstalling Windows, make a disk image from a bootable USB -- the symptoms seem to indicate possible disk corruption or damage. Then, with all your essential stuff protected in that image, check the drive S.M.A.R.T. status. Then try chkdsk and then SFC and DISM to first repair the drive and then to check and repair Windows OS. If that does not work, reinstallation, keeping files, is wort trying.

Answer (score 0):

> Am I faced with re-installing Windows or is there an easier way out of
> this mess?

You likely have no idea what has corrupted as a result of the sudden power outage.  So I suggest you reinstall Windows.

Check the drive first for hardware errors before reinstalling.

So reinstall is what I would do here.

You might look at a stronger True UPS to protect against this eventuality.

Comment: It's been some time; but, thank you for all the good help I received.

After poking around, I finally discovered that there were two connecting bolts inside the adjoining cabinets.  I never saw an installation like that, neither did the men from Home Depot who came to install the appliance.  

Thanks again, folks!